# Template render error: (unknown path) In NODE JS

Tags: json, node.js, express, render, nunjucks

I am developing a html page using node js.

My code for run app.js is

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

     res.render('index',{"data":["name" , "ABC"] });

});
```

i am trying to show name on my HTML page like:

```
{% data.name %}
```

i am getting an error which is Template render error: (unknown path) and   unknown block tag: data

I am using nunjucks as my engine.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#variables), you should write `{{ data.name }}` to access your variable member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using `{% ... %}` is for [template inheritance](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#template-inheritance). So the template engine will try to find a template matching `data.name`, and as it is unable to find it, it throws an error.

To display a [variable](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#variables) in your template, use: `{{ data.name }}`